# Median of ratio of independent variates with Beta distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, python, beta-distribution, scipy

Let $X, Y$ be independent random variables where $X \sim Beta(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$, $Y \sim Beta(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$, and $Z = X/Y$.

Recall $X, Y$ are supported on $(0,1)$, so $z > 0$.

I've computed several $pdf$'s of the distribution of $Z$ (for varying Beta's) using a formula from a paper I found and paid for [online](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/03610920008832632#.Vai6sBNViko), and have discovered *to my dismay* that the median of $Z$ is $1$.

I would love to submit my code but don't want to give away this formula because it costs \$48, but let's just say I am very sure there are no errors in it. For one thing, the area under the curve on $(0,\infty)$ is approximately $1$ (within 1e-8 according to Python's *scipy.integrate.quad* function) when I test several values for $\alpha_i,\beta_i$.

**My question is: Is this correct? Expected? Obvious even? Possibly obvious from the [hidden] formula which I'd assume most academics have access to?**

*Note: The reason this is surprising is because while the mean of the distribution behaves as one might expect: $\mathbb{E}X_1/\mathbb{E}Y_1 \leq \mathbb{E}X_2/\mathbb{E}Y_2 \implies \mathbb{E}Z_1 \leq \mathbb{E}Z_2$, the median does not seem to budge.

Happy to provide screenshots if anyone is interested.

Comment: Formulas are not secrets. If you want this question answered, then please be clear and state the formula.

Comment: I don't believe the claim in your question; I expect there's some omitted detail.

Comment: It's not hard to show that the median is a differentiable function of the four parameters with everywhere nonzero gradient. Consequently, the Implicit Function Theorem implies the set of parameters for which $Z$ has median $1$ is a codimension-one submanifold of $(0,\infty)^4$. Consequently, it is almost never the case that the median of $Z$ is $1$. Where you write about the "area under the curve is approximately $1$," it appears you have rediscovered the fact that the total probability of any random variable must be unity.

Comment: @whuber I will try to respond in more detail a bit later today, but for now will clarify that when I stated above the "the area under the curve is 1" was nothing to do with rediscovering the first axioms of what a probability measure was, but rather I was using this to spot check the formula for the pdf. I appreciate the vote of confidence though.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification--I certainly was wondering what that remark in your question had to do with the median!  That kind of calculation is indeed a smart way of checking a numerical integration routine.  It still would be nice to see a specific example of a (nontrivial) quartet of parameters for which your calculation indicates the median is $1$.

Comment: Have you really paid to get the distribution of $Z$ ? Ask your questions here next time, this is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without providing details and the precise meaning, the random variable $Y$ goes to $0$ when $\beta_2 \to \infty$ and $X/Y$ goes to $\infty$. Hence the median of $X/Y$ should go to $\infty$ too, and it can't be always $1$.

There is a case in which your statement is easily seen to be true. The median is $1$ means $\Pr(X/Y>1)=\frac12$ or in other words $\Pr(X>Y)=\frac12$. 
Then the statement is true when $X$ and $Y$ have the same distributions ($\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ and $\beta_1=\beta_2$), because of symmetry (thus a possible error in your 48\$ code is that it always sets $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$ and $\beta_1=\beta_2$).

Comment: I needed to sleep on this and went and saw my code was listing the same parameters accidentally.

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in comments, I don't believe the claim in your question (that the median of the ratio of two beta variates is 1); I expect there's some omitted detail.

Here's two such ratios, a Beta(10,1)/Beta(1,10) and Beta(1,10)/Beta(10,1) -- they have very different medians, neither anywhere near 1.

[image]

(R code)

```
x=rbeta(100000,10,1)
y=rbeta(100000,1,10)
plot(ecdf(x/y),xlim=c(0,20),ylim=c(0,1))
lines(ecdf(y/x),col=2)
abline(h=.5,col=8,lty=2)
abline(v=c(median(y/x),median(x/y)),col=c(2,1),lty=3)
```

Comment: Hi Glen_b, what are you using to generate this. Where do the functions `rbeta`, `plot`, `ecdf`, `lines`, `median`, and `abline` come from?

Comment: Also,, how do we know that the ratio you computed assumes independence of the random variables?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said that's R. Those are all R functions. Variates are generated independently\* by default ... you have to make them dependent. \*(more strictly, pseudorandom numbers are not truly perfectly independent, but they're constructed in such a way that make them behave for essentially any purpose like this as if they were independent; they'll be as independent as scipy's random generation will be)

Comment: Thanks -- I'm trying to do the same thing in Python but having some trouble....  will figure it out!

Comment: the essential steps of my algorithm were 1. generate $n$ x-values from a beta (skewed left) 2. generate $n$ y-values from a beta (skewed right). 3. Compute the ratios ($U_i=X_i/Y_i$) and find the median, (and plot). I also computed $V_i=Y_i/X_i$ to get the distribution of another ratio. $X_i$ and $Y_i$ will be effectively independent, as will $X_i$ and $X_j$ (and similarly for $Y$). So now $U_i$ and $U_{j\,\{j\neq i\}}$ should be independent as well. (While $U_i$ and $V_i$ will be dependent, that doesn't really impact what we're checking for here.)

Comment: This looks nice, however my concern is what happens when we have very steep looking pdf's and I am interested in using some general approach where the beta distributions get arbitrarily steep....

Comment: What I mean here is that a general step approach might work for mild looking distributions with a larger variance.

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at there, sorry.

Comment: I'm just saying that the simulation you described works well... in general. But imagine if you have a Beta distribution with the alpha and beta parameters sufficiently high.... then you have a pdf which resembles something close to a spike.  If your n is not large enough, your algorithm might simply 'skip' over the 'spike'....

Comment: No, since the algorithm above would simulate directly from the nearly-a-spike (perhaps you misunderstand what's going on there, but the algorithm will satisfactorily generate from betas with very high parameter values). It might perhaps be possible to make the parameters large enough that you could run into *numerical* issues with the algorithm, but at that point you could use direct algebraic approximations to high accuracy (indeed you could effectively write the median down by inspection).

Comment: Interesting... This is helpful.. I'm in a situation where I tried to implement the precise pdf given by the ratio of two independent beta distributions.  However this formula which I am using relies on the hypergeometric function, and scipy's implementation of this has been giving floating point errors. This is the reason I went back to this question. I want to empirically estimate the cdf. I can code the algorithm which you described and find an empirical cdf based on this, but my mathematically trained brain feels uncomfortable with this approach because I do not know the true error.

Comment: My next move is likely going to be to do some MCMC, it seems that those types of algorithms have a system in place by which to measure convergence...? I don't really know what to do and am new to this style of calculation.

Comment: I just generated a bunch of values with $\alpha=10^{12}$ and $\beta=10^{14}$. The distribution, mean and variance all seem to be as they should. Even  $\alpha=10^{16}$ and $\beta=10^{18}$ look okay, but it's about this point that it might be starting to encounter numerical issues (much earlier than getting to this point I'd instead pull out some scale factors from X and Y and simulate from Gaussians).

Comment: Your question on MCMC would be a new question (but search, since it may well have been asked and answered).

Comment: Okay thank you Glen. I think I know how to proceed now. Out of curiosity, what types of values for n did you use when looking at $\alpha, \beta > 10000$?

Comment: And when you say, "as they should" are you referring to the ratio or just the individual Beta rv you're pulling from?

Comment: In my simulations just now I did $n=10000$. The individual betas, though one can accurately approximate the mean and variance of the ratio for large $\alpha, \beta$ without simulation via [Taylor approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) (and higher moments if needed) and in principle check that against the simulation.

Comment: As numerator $α,β \to \infty$ and  denominator $α,β \to \infty$, asymptotically the ratio should be converging to normal (via Slutsky's theorem and convergence of the numerator to a normal if the ratio of numerator parameters $\beta/\alpha$ stays constant), so once you have the mean and variance via Taylor expansion you should have a good normal approximation to the distribution of the ratio that gets better as your parameters go higher.

Comment: This actually helps me a lot with what I'm trying to reverse engineer at work. I guess some previous employee was trying to make some assumptions about normality.... Thank you. very very helpful.

Comment: Though by what theorem is the fact that $\beta/\alpha$ staying constant come in? I'm wondering what can be said about the convergence rates and how they depend on the specific ratio. I will add this to another stack exchange question when I get another few minutes.

Comment: It's not a theorem that it stays constant. It's something under your control. We're trying to discuss what happens as the parameters become very large.. *If* you increase them both in proportion, so the ratio is constant, then they converge to a constant value (and we can discuss the properties of the distribution of the ratio of beta variables). If you don't keep them in proportion, neither of the beta variates will converge on a constant value. Recall that it was *you* who raised the notion of convergence to "a spike". ...ctd

Comment: ctd... If you don't hold alpha/beta constant as the parameters increase you there's not a single value for the spike to converge on -- the thing can wander about anywhere on the positive half-line, which isn't convergence in the required sense.

Comment: I will try to move some of this conversation up into my answer when I get a chance.

Comment: I get what you're saying. It seemed that you mentioned two things: 1) Slutsky's theorem implies some results around the normality of the ratio of two Beta distributions and 2) more formally if $\rho \cdot k = \alpha_k, k = \beta_k, \rho > 0$, $X_k \sim B(\alpha_k,\beta_k)$ are random variables, then $X_k \rightarrow N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, but I guess what I'm asking is what theorem does this come from?

Comment: 1. SLutsky only tells us that if the denominator converges to $c$ the ratio will converge to whatever the numerator converges to divided by $c$. A different result tells us the numerator goes to a normal. 2. An actual theorem for the numerator would establish something of the form $(X_k-\mu_k)/\sigma_k\to N(0,1)$. ... and for that, you should ask a new question. If my claim is true, it's useful as a question in its own right. One way to establish such things would be via properties of the mgf or characteristic function